# Recorrer una clase y enviar cada elemento a una ruta diferente

Tags: flutter, listview

ahora mismo estoy bloqueado en mi aprendizaje en flutter (novato), ya que debo encontrar la forma de recorrer una clase que forma un grid de categorías, eso lo consigo, puedo mostrar el listview con el texto de cada categoria, una imagen de fondo diferente para cada elemento, pero el problema lo tengo a la hora de recorrer las rutas.

ahora mismo estoy probando diferentes formas, en otra pregunta me han recomendado usar Navigator.pushNamed(), ya que debo pasar la ruta desde un String.

mi sintaxis ahora mismo es la siguiente, errónea.

```
    onTap: () {
Navigator.pushNamed( context , _gridItems[index].route);}
```

---

```
class GridItems {
  String category, urlimg, route;

  GridItems(this.categoria, this.urlimg, this.route);
}
```

---

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields
  List<GridItems> _gridItems = [
    GridItems("Amor", "amor.jpg", "Amor()"),    <--- //aquí es donde no doy con la forma de especificar que es un widget y no un array..
  ];
```

la segunda solución seria especificar que el tercer elemento de mi clase es un widget y cargarlo con un navigator.push, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar, si alguien puede facilitarme un ejemplo lo agradecería enormemente.

La idea es conseguir que cada elemento que se genera mande a un nuevo widget, recorriendo el array que contiene los diferentes datos..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que no estas guardando la ruta como tal, estas guardando el nombre de la clase, en la clase main tienes que declara las rutas de tus clases:

```
     MaterialApp(
        title: 'Nombre de tu app'
        routes: {
        'amor': (_) => Amor(),
        },
        initialRoute: 'La ruta inicial',  
  );
```

Ahora en vez de llamar a "Amor()", llama a "amor". Eso te deberia de funcionar:

```
List<GridItems> _gridItems = [
GridItems("Amor", "amor.jpg", "amor"),
```

];

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo! pude solucionar mi problema gracias a tu respuesta.